# Youtube Views and Likes

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to find out which people have viewed or liked your video on YouTube ?
YouTube Only provides data like , how many percentage of views comes Region wise.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot, and this is a good thing for privacy reasons.

Using the [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) you can get general statistics for a list of videos as part of a `contentDetails` structure:

```
 "statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "likeCount": unsigned long,
    "dislikeCount": unsigned long,
    "favoriteCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long
  },
```

Comment: Where can I run this code?

Comment: @LCarvalho It's a REST API. See examples: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it